# Accessing value from JSON_decode array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

i am trying to access a value from a JSON response in PHP.

Here's the JSON output:

[JSON Response](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=tacoma,wa&imgtype=photo&imgsz=small%7Cmedium%7Clarge%7Cxlarge)

```
{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"1080","height":"720","imageId":"ANd9GcQWSDt_-TnzrNvEGEUoRSi56HfnP6GYXU5nDZYTH-jWw85xAZTOmtjjU5fq","tbWidth":"150","tbHeight":"100","unescapedUrl":"http://jblm-realestateguide.com/wp-content/gallery/fort-lewis-housing-areas_1/tacoma.jpg","url":"http://jblm-realestateguide.com/wp-content/gallery/fort-lewis-housing-areas_1/tacoma.jpg","visibleUrl":"jblm-realestateguide.com","title":"Cities Around Joint Base Lewis McChord, \u003cb\u003eWashington\u003c/b\u003e | Joint Base \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e","titleNoFormatting":"Cities Around Joint Base Lewis McChord, Washington | Joint Base ...","originalContextUrl":"http://jblm-realestateguide.com/cities-around-jblm/","content":"\u003cb\u003eTacoma\u003c/b\u003e, \u003cb\u003eWA\u003c/b\u003e","contentNoFormatting":"Tacoma, WA","tbUrl":"http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcQWSDt_-TnzrNvEGEUoRSi56HfnP6GYXU5nDZYTH-jWw85xAZTOmtjjU5fq"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"441","height":"441","imageId":"ANd9GcRTxtYjg8d_R9V_fcu9WT2oThkLEzSOBrtnD5yh7sDv3EQ0mc1Ba8GQ4Z4","tbWidth":"127","tbHeight":"127","unescapedUrl":"http://washingtonhottubspacovers.com/imgs/tacoma-wa.jpg","url":"http://washingtonhottubspacovers.com/imgs/tacoma-wa.jpg","visibleUrl":"washingtonhottubspacovers.com","title":"\u003cb\u003eTacoma Washington\u003c/b\u003e Replacement Hot Tub Covers","titleNoFormatting":"Tacoma Washington Replacement Hot Tub Covers","originalContextUrl":"http://washingtonhottubspacovers.com/tacoma-hot-tub-covers.html","content":"\u003cb\u003eTacoma Washington\u003c/b\u003e Replacement","contentNoFormatting":"Tacoma Washington Replacement","tbUrl":"http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRTxtYjg8d_R9V_fcu9WT2oThkLEzSOBrtnD5yh7sDv3EQ0mc1Ba8GQ4Z4"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"800","height":"534","imageId":"ANd9GcTLGrihrETQp8EcOYZdoJtsFRRHOuMEUCQZ3I8fUrhJJw4JX1xOAzvC3Qg","tbWidth":"150","tbHeight":"100","unescapedUrl":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-79aR6CKFGcg/Tc2eit4NyjI/AAAAAAAAAAk/D1L0QcZ4-Aw/w800-h800/Rainier84_mount_rainier_and_tacoma_08-20-84.jpg","url":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-79aR6CKFGcg/Tc2eit4NyjI/AAAAAAAAAAk/D1L0QcZ4-Aw/w800-h800/Rainier84_mount_rainier_and_tacoma_08-20-84.jpg","visibleUrl":"plus.google.com","title":"Ken Williams,CHFC CLTC CLU - Google+","titleNoFormatting":"Ken Williams,CHFC CLTC CLU - Google+","originalContextUrl":"https://plus.google.com/113866325996254808746","content":"Scrapbook photo 3","contentNoFormatting":"Scrapbook photo 3","tbUrl":"http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcTLGrihrETQp8EcOYZdoJtsFRRHOuMEUCQZ3I8fUrhJJw4JX1xOAzvC3Qg"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"350","height":"238","imageId":"ANd9GcSmbeFTC2odTglWyJ2hjAuly1HJPNGPNvr2g4BsYy9haSF0aPHg4JN4YxU","tbWidth":"120","tbHeight":"82","unescapedUrl":"http://www.come2tacoma.com/images/tacoma_rainer.jpg","url":"http://www.come2tacoma.com/images/tacoma_rainer.jpg","visibleUrl":"www.come2tacoma.com","title":"\u003cb\u003etacoma\u003c/b\u003e_rainer.jpg","titleNoFormatting":"tacoma_rainer.jpg","originalContextUrl":"http://www.come2tacoma.com/","content":"County \u003cb\u003eWashington\u003c/b\u003e. \u003cb\u003eTacoma\u003c/b\u003e","contentNoFormatting":"County Washington. Tacoma","tbUrl":"http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcSmbeFTC2odTglWyJ2hjAuly1HJPNGPNvr2g4BsYy9haSF0aPHg4JN4YxU"}],"cursor":{"resultCount":"5,250,000","pages":[{"start":"0","label":1},{"start":"4","label":2},{"start":"8","label":3},{"start":"12","label":4},{"start":"16","label":5},{"start":"20","label":6},{"start":"24","label":7},{"start":"28","label":8}],"estimatedResultCount":"5250000","currentPageIndex":0,"moreResultsUrl":"http://www.google.com/images?oe\u003dutf8\u0026ie\u003dutf8\u0026source\u003duds\u0026start\u003d0\u0026imgsz\u003dsmall%7Cmedium%7Clarge%7Cxlarge\u0026imgtype\u003dphoto\u0026hl\u003den\u0026q\u003dtacoma,wa","searchResultTime":"0.17"}}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
```

PHP CODE:

```
$get_location_info = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_url),true);        
$location_image =  $get_location_info->responseData->results[0]->{'unescapedUrl'};
```

I am trying to access the "unescapedUrl" value from the JSON response and capture it in PHP. I am currently getting a NULL for $location_image in above code.

Any idea what i am doing wrong above? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_decode returns an [Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

To access the unescapedUrl you would need to try something like this

`$location_image =  $get_location_info['responseData']['results'][0]['unescapedUrl'];`

you can also iterate over the results using

```
foreach($get_location_info['responseData']['results'] as $result){

    echo $result['unescapedUrl'];
}
```

Comment: It only returns an array if you pass the 2nd param $assoc=true otherwise it defaults to stdClass Objects.

Comment: I omitted that because in his question he passes `true` as the 2nd param

Comment: you can pass the 2nd parameter as false

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$get_location_info['responseData']['results'][0]['unescapedUrl']
```

If you weren't using the "true" condition would be something like this

```
$get_location_info->responseData->results[0]->unescapedUrl
```

Keep in mind that the "results" bit of this data structure is an array, therefore you should loop through it to get all the "unsescapedUrl" values.

Comment: Wont work based on the question which passes `true` as 2nd param to `json_decode`.

Comment: Nevermind, my mistake, I was seeing it other way, I'll edit this!

Comment: I hope you didn't just copy my answer.

Comment: RPM, no, I fixed mine, I checked it out again and saw my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the 2nd param in json_decode, $assoc=true. This returns an associative array instead of the object for the notation you are using.

Update this line to:

```
$get_location_info = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_url));
```

without the true param and your object notation will work.  And if not do what tf.alves suggested

```
$location_image =  $get_location_info->responseData->results[0]->unescapedUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are ultimately transforming the JSON into a PHP array, you need to use this syntax:

```
$count = count($get_location_info['responseData']['results']);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
     echo $get_location_info['responseData']['results'][$i]['unescapedUrl'];
```

Either use an array or object.